# Steps for calculating the derivative of the expectation of a max operator

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, expectation

I have the following expression:

$$ \mathbb{E}\left[C\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\alpha \max\{\tilde{\tau} - t , 0 \} + \gamma \tilde{\tau} \right]$$

where $\tilde{\tau} = \tau + \sigma \tilde{\varepsilon}$ and where $\tilde{\varepsilon}$ is a standard normal variable with mean zero and variance equal to one. $\alpha$, $\gamma$ and $\sigma$ are just parameters. I need to take the derivative of this expression with respect to $\tau$. Before doing that I re-write the expression above as:

$$ \mathbb{E}\left[C\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \alpha \max\{\tau +\sigma \tilde{\varepsilon} - t , 0 \} + \gamma \left(\tau + \sigma \tilde{\varepsilon} \right) \right]$$

$$ \mathbb{E}\left[C\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \alpha \max\{\tau +\sigma \tilde{\varepsilon} - t , 0 \} \right] + \gamma\tau + \sigma \mathbb{E} \left[\tilde{\varepsilon} \right]$$

$$ \mathbb{E}\left[C\right] = \alpha \mathbb{E}\left[\max\{\tau +\sigma \tilde{\varepsilon} - t , 0 \} \right] + \gamma\tau $$

The derivative with respect to $\tau$ is:

$$ \dfrac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[C\right]}{\partial \tau} = \alpha \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \tau} \int  \max\{\tau +\sigma \tilde{\varepsilon} - t , 0 \} f(\tilde{\tau}) d \tilde{\tau}+ \gamma $$

I assume the functions satisfy the conditions that allow us to interchange differentiation and integration, hence

$$ \dfrac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[C\right]}{\partial \tau} = \alpha \int \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \tau} \max\{\tau +\sigma \tilde{\varepsilon} - t , 0 \} f(\tilde{\tau}) d \tilde{\tau}+ \gamma $$

Using the product rule:

$$ \dfrac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[C\right]}{\partial \tau} = \alpha \int  \max\{1,0\}f(\tilde{\tau}) d \tilde{\tau} + \int \max\{\tau +\sigma \tilde{\varepsilon} - t , 0 \} f'(\tilde{\tau}) d \tilde{\tau}+ \gamma $$

$$ \dfrac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[C\right]}{\partial \tau} = \alpha \int f(\tilde{\tau}) d \tilde{\tau} + \int \max\{\tau +\sigma \tilde{\varepsilon} - t , 0 \} f'(\tilde{\tau}) d \tilde{\tau}+ \gamma $$

$$ \dfrac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[C\right]}{\partial \tau} = \alpha F(\tilde{\tau}) + \int \max\{\tau +\sigma \tilde{\varepsilon} - t , 0 \} f'(\tilde{\tau}) d \tilde{\tau}+ \gamma $$

The next step is where I am a bit doubtful. Does the second term go to zero because I can redefine $f'(\tilde{\tau})$ with $\varepsilon$ so that computing the expectation of $\varepsilon$ gives me zero and makes the second term vanish... or can "I distribute" the integral inside the max operator and exploit the fact that $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, so that all of these terms in the max operator have mean zero?

Finally, last question: The official answer is:

$$ \dfrac{\partial \mathbb{E}\left[C\right]}{\partial \tau} = \alpha \mathbb{P}(\tau + \sigma \varepsilon - t > 0) +  \gamma $$

I understand that $F(a)$ means $\mathbb{P}(\tilde{\tau}<a)$ but I am a bit confused with getting from $F(\tilde{\tau})$ to

$$ \mathbb{P}(\tau + \sigma \varepsilon - t > 0) $$

Comment: One can start from the function $$g(x)=E(\max\{\tilde\epsilon,x\})$$ and note that $$g'(x)=P(\tilde\epsilon\leqslant x)=\Phi(x)$$ Now, $$E(C)=E(\alpha \max\{\tau + \sigma \tilde{\varepsilon} - t , 0 \}) + \gamma\tau + \gamma\sigma E(\tilde{\varepsilon})$$ hence $$E(C)=\alpha(\tau-t)+\alpha E(\max\{ \sigma \tilde{\varepsilon} , t-\tau \}) + \gamma\tau$$ that is, $$E(C)=(\alpha+\gamma)\tau-\alpha t+\alpha\sigma g((t-\tau)/\sigma)$$ which yields $$\frac{d E(C)}{d\tau}=\alpha+\gamma-\alpha\Phi((t-\tau)/\sigma)=\gamma-\alpha\Phi((\tau-t)/\sigma)$$ which is equivalent to the formula in your post.

Comment: @Did Thank you so much. You may have noticed this is where I got stuck. I tried to redefine my question in a simpler way but failed to do so. Two questions: 1) Why is it that $g'(x) = P(\tilde{\varepsilon} \leq x) = \Phi(x)$? 2) Should I drop the other question I asked, seems to be confusing.

Comment: Re 1, really you have no idea to approach it?

Comment: @Did No, do you have any suggestions or could you show the derivation? Could this work: $g(x) = E[\tilde{\varepsilon}*P(\tilde{\varepsilon}>x)]  + E[x*P(x>\tilde{\varepsilon})]$

Comment: $$g(x)=x\Phi(x)+\int_x^\infty y\varphi(y)dy$$

Comment: I get that this formula works but I don't know how is this related to the expectation of the max, how can I derive this formula from the expectation of a max function?